# Using SQL Server Native Client With Pyodbc on Linux

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, redhat, pyodbc

I'm trying to use Python on a RedHat machine to connect to a SQL Server database using the Microsoft provided driver.  I know the driver is working because I can connect using the sqlcmd.  The following in Python yields an error. It seems that pyodbc can't find the driver.  Anybody know how to fix this?

```
conStr = 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server='+server+';Database='+db+';  
UID='+u+';PWD='+pw+';'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conStr)

pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that on Linux I needed to remove the braces around the driver name.

Some more info on the Driver keyword can be gleaned from here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568455

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You can use pymssql to connect SQLServer in python.
It's easy to use, similar with MySQL-python lib.

http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/

Answer (score 0):

Since pyodbc is going through unixODBC, can you confirm odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini are correctly set up?